# borders around content with jquery masonry/isotope (not having spaces)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, border

I currently am using masonry plugin with jquery. I have a few boxes. I want to be able to create boxes where they touch and have no space. Now I'm trying to create borders around these containers, but when I do

```
border:thin solid black;
```

in css, it borders around everything. So if there are containers next to each other, it will pretty much border double. Unless there's a way to have the containers overlap each other so the border lines will just line up right on top of each other. So far it just either makes the container go to next row, or i would have to widen the width so it shows the double lines.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.container',
            columnWidth: 1,
            isFitWidth: true,
            position:'relative',
            animationOptions: 
            {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your css like this:

```
#main {
    width:300px;

}
.container {
width:50px;
height:80px;
border:1px solid black;
margin-right: -1px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

here the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/wsk7C/6/

Comment: I see that you've used isotope, does that mean it only works in isotope? cause i tried setting my masonry columnWidth to 1 and it still makes a "double" line.

Comment: @andrewliu: can you show me your the code which you have made

Comment: view your js, there should be no container between box. Have you check the opening and closing your html-tag?

Comment: what do you mean no container between box?

Comment: no-space beetwen box. Well, I probably misunderstood the workings of your code. Do you have a demo on jsfiddle.net to make me more clearly know the error.

Comment: I did a quick script on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wsk7C/4/ . You can see that there will be a darker line in between the containers, so instaed of 1px, its 2px like because two containers are right next to each other

Comment: Hohoho.. i see.. check a new code above, i hope its the solution for you.